# After Foreman install, my Icinga interface is not working

Tags: icinga, foreman

I installed Foreman now my nagios (Icinga actually) is not working. The URL is /icinga/ but it just says:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

Icinga is running.

Anyone know why this may be?

Foreman log states the following so I guess Foreman has taken over apache/port 80/something??

```
Completed 201 Created in 82.6ms (Views: 11.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/icinga/" for 2.102.91.108 at 2014-09-24 20:50:55 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/icinga"):
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:142:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

Thanks

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Have updated the post above to show Foreman logs with icinga routing errors

Answer (score 2):

Got my /icinga/ working, foreman must have altered the Apache config which I consider quite bad...

First in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled I renamed:

```
05-foreman.conf-> 05-foreman.conf.bkp
05-foreman-ssl.conf-> 05-foreman-ssl.conf.bkp
```

Then restarted Apache. This means the Apache foreman files will not load on the web root and take over all my other vhosts.

Second, for some reason authn_core.load and rewrite.load were not loaded anymore, so I had to load these again:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/authn_core.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authn_core.load
```

Then I could see the conf-available apache conf files were not being loaded anymore, and this is where icinga.conf is, so in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf I had to add:

```
Include "/etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf"
```

Then an apache restart meant /icinga was up and running again with no foreman taking over it.

Next job is for me to get foreman up and running on an alias and not on the web root, so it wont take over my other software.