# Changing the Default Foreman URI

Tags: httpd.conf, foreman

I have just installed the latest instance of foreman on a RHEL 7.1 VM.
Now that it is installed the httpd configuration has changed so that the foreman URI is http(s)://(server)/.

This has broken everything else running on the server such as nagios.

I have tried changing the default foreman configuration to http(s)://(server)/foreman but at this point in time nothing is working.
Previously identical questions [Serving directory listing in Foreman](https://serverfault.com/questions/708232/serving-directory-listing-in-foreman) & [After Foreman install, my Icinga interface is not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/630985/after-foreman-install-my-icinga-interface-is-not-working)
were asked. But there has never been an answer on how to resolve what should be a common issue.

That being said I had tried using

```
Alias /foreman "/usr/share/foreman/public"
```

in the configuration file for both 05-foreman.conf & 05-foreman-ssl.conf with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to find the answer to how to configure foreman to use
http(s)://(server>/foreman.

`/etc/foreman/foreman-installer/answers.yaml`

Contains the option to dictate the URL that foreman will use. This file overrides the defaults for the installation process.
overrides can be provided when running /usr/sbin/foreman-installer the override in question would be:

```
/usr/sbin/foreman-installer --foreman-foreman-url
```